# imagick php5 addon on ubuntu 64bit isn't working

Tags: 64-bit, lamp, xampp, imagemagick

I have a lampp webserver and i need to edit animated gif files.
I have tried to install imagick with [this tutorial](http://answers.bitnami.org/questions/3863/how-to-install-imagemagick-and-php-module-imagick-on-ubuntu-64bit).
But at the "make" commad i get the error

```
can't read /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.la: No such file or directory
```

i already managed to install the 32bit version, but the server gives me an error:

```
Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/imagick.so' - /opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/imagick.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64 in Unknown on line 0
```

I googeld the error and someone said, that the server want a 64bit version of the file...

I'm new to compiling files and never installed addons on my webserver...
If you  need aditional informations, logs or some file, please tell me

(Sorry for my bad english :D)

Answer (score 1):

It is now bit too late, but here I come with the proper solution to install iMagick with LAMP or XAMPP Server on Linux based systems. It is only the iMagick extension of PECL that works with PHP. So you don't have to worry for Image Magick and Magick Wand to install.

First of all remove everything you have tried to make it work. Uninstall ImageMagick with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get remove imagemagick
```

Remove ImageMagick and all its dependencies with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove imagemagick
```

Purge the config file of ImageMagick with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get purge imagemagick
```

Or similarly, like this:

```
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove imagemagick
```

Well, all your previous installation files are just gone.
Now Install it purely and perfectly without any conflict or file modification. Enter the following two commands:

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
sudo apt-get install php5-imagick
```

That was way too easy - thanks interwebs!
Remember to restart/reload your webserver..

```
sudo service apache2 graceful
```

That's all. Check your php.ini or test with any simple script.